# How to indicate if a row contains more than one new word?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

E.g.

1. | boy | - no indication because there is only one new value that previously wasn't contained in the spreadsheet
2. | the boy | - no indication
3. | the boy sings | - no indication
4. | the boy sings at night | - indication of some sort because both "at" and "night" were not previously contained in the spreadsheet.

I assume the indication would either be a highlighting of the row or the row next to it displaying a count.

Answer (score 1):

Got answered on reddit from user 6745408

You'll need two formulas

For `A1`

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1," "))
```

For `A2` on..

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT($A2," ")),"select Count(Col1) where not Col1 matches '"&JOIN("|",REGEXREPLACE($A$1:A1," ","|"))&"' label Count(Col1) ''"))=2
```

The second one is long, but we need to strip out all of the previous lines so we can count the new words.